# Antiforgery token and object parameter do not post to MVC4 Controller action accordingly

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken

I have a controller action which has a class as a parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(vm.Quotation quotationheaders)
    {...
```

and calls it using

```
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
quotationheader.__RequestVerificationToken = token;

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '/someapp/quotation/create/',
        data: quotation,
        async: true,
        success: function (response1) {
            alert(response1);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            ThrowException(error);
        }

    });
```

the data object contains members which also have nested array of details (qutoation header and product details). Using the code above I do not have problem with ANTIFORGERY filter. it seems the controller action reconizes it. However, the product detail properties of the quotaion (nested array of object) are all **null**. It wasn't able to Bind to the model although the header properties were passed accordingly.

So I did some modification and changed the data and stringify it.

```
data: JSON.stringify(quotation),
```

This time, the controller action cannot recognize the verification token. So I tried to remove the AntiForgery and saw that the details were bound accordingly.

As summary:
ajax data stringify:  binding is ok but verification token is not recognized.
ajax data object:     the verification token is verified and but the object detail collection properties are null.

Can any body suggest a rightful way to do this?

Thanks!